# Google Apps Script UiApp using Apps styled widgets

Tags: google-apps-script

Can I somehow use the theme/style of Google Apps like docs and gmail in a UiApp form?
I would like to keep my interface consistent with the rest of the Google services.

Comment: Not simply. The "theme" on the UiApp elements is pretty static and not up for much re-styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can get fairly close with HtmlService, but it's harder to do it in UiApp. Not impossible, but substantially harder for sure.

Comment: For my own reasons I want to stick with UiApp instead of HtmlService. But for the matter of others interested in your solution, could you expand it a bit more? In your case should one create and load custom css rules for all html elements matching the desired look (like https://sites.google.com/site/gashackja/gas-bootstrap does)?

Comment: Yes, essentially that's the idea. The UiApp allowed styles are more restrictive, which makes fidelity a bit harder, but in HtmlService you can apply most styles.